# Android Studio doesn´t recognize Fragment to Facebook Button

Tags: java, android, fragment

I´m trying to make an aplication with a button to login in Facebook, I´m adding my facebook button insaid the fragment XML, I have this class:

```
package com.cheesecake.clasi.facebooklogin;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

/**
 * Created by Leonardo on 21/04/2015.
 */
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

public MyFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveStanceState){
    super.onCreate(saveStanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle saveStanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle saveStateStation){
    super.onViewCreated(view, saveStateStation);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    //loginButton.setReadPermissions("users_friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    }
}
```

When I add loginButton.setFragment(this) (it needs a Fragment) it shows an error:

```
Error:(37, 20) error: method setFragment in class FacebookButtonBase cannot be applied to given types;`enter code here` required: Fragment found: MyFragment reason: actual argument MyFragment cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion
```

I don't understand that, because "MyFragment" is just the name.

Comment: it is not mandatory to create fragment, you can do it in activity directly and do not use this button in code at all unless you need customized behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even not looking for my comment above, the issue is your `Fragment` is `android.app.Fragment;` change it to one from support library `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a wrapper for native fragments:

```
public class NativeFragmentWrapper extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private final Fragment nativeFragment;

    public NativeFragmentWrapper(Fragment nativeFragment) {
        this.nativeFragment = nativeFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        nativeFragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        nativeFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

And then use this in your code:

```
loginButton(new NativeFragmentWrapper(this));
```

Comment: nice hack you got there, worked like a charm. +1
my problem was i am using AccountAuthenticatorActivity and there is no supportFragmentManager in that one. So either i had to hack the activity or the login button.